# How to get the map_region from CLPlaceMark

Tags: ios, clplacemark

I have to take out the map_region and type from CLPlaceMark but I couldn't find a property which will give the map_region values in CLPlaceMark Class.

```
 {
        placeData =     {
            component =         (
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_HOURS";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_RATING";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_FLYOVER";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_BOUNDS";
                    value =                 (
                                            {
                            bounds =                         {
                                "map_region" =                             {
                                    eastLng = "-73.832921";
                                    northLat = "40.739434";
                                    southLat = "40.550334";
                                    westLng = "-74.056687";
                                };
                            };
                        }
                    );
                    "values_available" = 1;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ROAD_ACCESS_INFO";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_PLACE_INFO";
                    value =                 (
                                            {
                            "place_info" =                         {
                                center =                             {
                                    lat = "40.692529";
                                    lng = "-73.990996";
                                };
                                timezone =                             {
                                    identifier = "America/New_York";
                                };
                            };
                        }
                    );
                    "values_available" = 1;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ENTITY";
                    value =                 (
                                            {
                            entity =                         {
                                "is_disputed" = 0;
                                name =                             (
                                                                    {
                                        locale = "en_US";
                                        "string_value" = Brooklyn;
                                    }
                                );
                                type = "SUB_LOCALITY";
                            };
                        }
                    );
                    "values_available" = 1;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ADDRESS";
                    value =                 (
                                            {
                            address =                         {
                                "localized_address" =                             (
                                                                    {
                                        address =                                     {
                                            formattedAddressLine =                                         (
                                                "Brooklyn, NY",
                                                "United States"
                                            );
                                            structuredAddress =                                         {
                                                administrativeArea = "New York";
                                                administrativeAreaCode = NY;
                                                areaOfInterest =                                             (
                                                    "Long Island"
                                                );
                                                country = "United States";
                                                countryCode = US;
                                                geoId =                                             (
                                                );
                                                locality = Brooklyn;
                                                subAdministrativeArea = Kings;
                                            };
                                        };
                                        locale = "en_US";
                                    }
                                );
                            };
                        }
                    );
                    "values_available" = 1;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_AMENITIES";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_STYLE_ATTRIBUTES";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                },
                            {
                    "cache_control" = UNCACHEABLE;
                    "start_index" = 0;
                    status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
                    type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_BUSINESS_CLAIM";
                    "values_available" = 0;
                }
            );
            "result_provider_id" = 6489;
            status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
        };
    }
```

Is there any way to read the values from CLPlaceMark class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLPlacemark` does not have any properties to access it's underlaying storage data (private `GEOMapItemStorage`). There is however a way how to access these data although it's a hacky way and you should use it very carefully.

When you try to print your `CLPlacemark` instance console logs also `GEOMapItemStorage` so theoretically you can access this string and convert it into a dictionary. Tricky part is that it's a raw string and you have to process it little bit. I am posting an extension to `CLPlacemark` that should does the job and returns `[String: AnyObject]?`.

```
extension CLPlacemark {

    enum GeoMapItemStorageError: ErrorType {
        case InvalidFormat
        case DataEncoding
        case Serialization(underlaying: ErrorType)
    }

    func extractGeoMapItemStorage() throws -> [String: AnyObject]? {

        let description = self.description as NSString
        let indexOfBracket = description.rangeOfString("{", options: NSStringCompareOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

        guard indexOfBracket.location != NSNotFound else {
            throw GeoMapItemStorageError.InvalidFormat
        }

        let dictString = description.substringFromIndex(indexOfBracket.location)

        guard let dictStringData = dictString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
            throw GeoMapItemStorageError.DataEncoding
        }

        do {
            return try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(
                dictStringData,
                options: NSPropertyListReadOptions.Immutable,
                format: nil
                ) as? [String: AnyObject]
        }
        catch (let error){
            throw GeoMapItemStorageError.Serialization(underlaying: error)
        }

    }
}
```